# retrieve value in a column corresponding to the first occurrence of an element in another column in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['x','x','y','y','y','z','y','y'],'b':np.random.randn(8)})

    a    b
0   x   -0.2414
1   x   1.2214
2   y   0.3442      
3   y   -2.9492
4   y   0.1214
5   z   2.8102
6   y   -1.3844
7   y   -0.7363
```

What is the most efficient way to select the value in column `b` that corresponds to the first occurrence of a letter in column `a` that is different from the previous letter?
This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
    a   b
0   x   -0.2414
2   y   0.3442
5   z   2.8102
6   y   -1.3844
```

Comment: Happy, why is y on your output twice?  do you only want the first occurrence?

Comment: @EoinS: It should be the first occurrence of a letter that is different from the previous letter. So I'd like to retrieve the first x. Then the first y that comes after all the previous x's. Then the first z after all the previous y's. Finally the first y after the z. It's really difficult putting into words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[df['a'] != df['a'].shift(1)]
Out[22]: 
   a         b
0  x  0.564161
2  y  1.498050
5  z  0.080116
6  y  0.255031
```

Original dataframe I used:

```
df
Out[23]: 
   a         b
0  x  0.564161
1  x -1.153969
2  y  1.498050
3  y  0.067259
4  y -0.345102
5  z  0.080116
6  y  0.255031
7  y  0.345250
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `groupby` with `a` the way I would do it is:

```
g = df.groupby('a')
g.first()
```

Once you have your data grouped, `first` returns the initial occurrence of `a`

[Pandas groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)